# how connect to mysql from oracle form

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i, oracleforms

I would like to know can I connect to MySQL from Oracle forms? if yes would you put and example for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a database link in your Oracle DB that points at your MySQL DB. Then you can write queries such as this:

select * from oracle_table_1, mysql_table@mysql_link;

[This document](http://www.pythian.com/news/1554/how-to-access-mysql-from-oracle-with-odbc-and-sql/) appears to have some helpful information on how to set all this up; apparently this isn't the simplest of tasks.

Comment: It's not that hard. Missing is the part about the compilation and installation of the ODBC driver and driver manager.

Comment: The link is no more valid. Any suggestion ?